# How can I compare duplicate columns, each with a range of numbers, and return error if their ranges of numbers overlap to each other?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, excel-formula, flatten, google-query-language

I am fairly new to googlesheets and I apologize for the poor explanation beforehand.
As the title suggests, what I'm trying to figure out using googlesheet formulas is:

1. Go through an entire column for duplicates
2. Within those duplicates, compare their ranges of numbers and check for any overlapping number
3. If any number overlaps, return error

Google Sheet Link : [Click Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B45_Kn-MNGvhzlINBmf4zYofWbaS8guYqB0M6-xOx6Y/edit#gid=0)

Within the googlesheet above, Row 13 would have a problem since Row 13's Math's Page 8 overlaps with Row 8's Page 8.

So far, what I had in mind and tried was to split ranges of numbers into multiple columns so that I could compare each of those columns to duplicates' ranges of numbers, but I'm not sure what to do after from here. Another assumption is that I would need only to compare only the latest column to check for duplicate Course and overlapping range, but I'm not sure what to use here too.

I appreciate any tips and/or formulas to try out.

Comment: "If any number overlaps, return error" - only for that number or the whole cell ?

Comment: either works for the returning error, but I believe this can be done by using conditional formatting? Or did you mean overlapping numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={"Warning"; INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B3:B&"", TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(QUERY({SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, D3:D), ","))),
 QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(D3:D, ","))="",,B3:B)), 
 "where Col1 is not null")&"×", 
 IF(COUNTIFS(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(D3:D, ","))="",,C3:C&SPLIT(D3:D, ","))),
 "where Col1 is not null"), 
 QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(D3:D, ","))="",,C3:C&SPLIT(D3:D, ","))),
 "where Col1 is not null"), SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, D3:D), ","))), 
 "<="&SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, D3:D), ","))))>1, "Error,", 
 QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(D3:D, ","))="",,SPLIT(D3:D, ","))), 
 "where Col1 is not null")&",")}, 
 "select max(Col3) group by Col1 pivot Col2"),,9^9)), "×")), 2, 0)), ",$", ), ", ", ","))}
```

[image]

Comment: Whoa, thanks! I appreciate your help and I will read the entire formula multiple times to fully understand it.

Comment: I know I'm already asking more than enough but do you think it's possible to tweak / simplify the formula so that the warning column returns error only if there's an overlapping number? Something like arrayformula(if(there's an overlapping number), "error", ""). In this sense, I would assume it would only work if the formula is written per row.

Comment: @Michael possible but what should be the output for lets say D14 ? `Error, Error`? co if we remove number that 10 in between will vanish too

Comment: I think vanishing is fine. For each row's output for warning, just `Error` (or "err" as string, etc.) is fine if the formula gets simplified and needs to be written each row.

Comment: @Michael see your sheet:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP5j0.png

Comment: Just saw it, thank you. Again, but I really appreciate your help.