# How to compare duplicate columns and compare their range of number values to check and return for any overlapping values?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

this is an extended question to the previous question I asked here : [How can I compare duplicate columns, each with a range of numbers, and return error if their ranges of numbers overlap to each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68900606/how-can-i-compare-duplicate-columns-each-with-a-range-of-numbers-and-return-er)
The question above was answered but the formula seemed to break and return error if I were to use and apply for a sheet that has values over 700+ cells. Google Sheet Link : [Click Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N2iHQLxGIfY-ApCnSF57vRBWJkXXoj_vrlx8fIXt7Pc/edit#gid=108222797)

As the title suggests, is it possible to use googlesheet formula to go through:

1. Go through an entire column (Column C) for duplicates,
2. Within those duplicates, compare their ranges of numbers that are set right next to their cells (Column D),
3. And check for any overlapping numbers.

I appreciate any tips and / or formulas.

Comment: `but the formula seemed to break and return error if I were to use and apply for a sheet that has values over 700+ cells` I tried using it with ~800 rows of values and it didn't show any error. Can you please provide more details about this? Consider providing a reproducible sample.

Comment: odd...it seemed to be inconsistent that it'd show errors on random columns that I thought the formula was broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that what you need?

[image]

**err** in case any page for this course is seen in more than 2 places. For example page 1 for English.

Here's the formula:

```
={
  "Warning";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IFS(
      C3:C = "",,
      D3:D = "",,
      IFNA(
      REGEXMATCH(
        TO_TEXT(D3:D),
          "(?:^|,)"
        & VLOOKUP(
            C3:C,
            SPLIT(
              REGEXREPLACE(
                TRANSPOSE(QUERY(
                  QUERY(
                    QUERY(
                      QUERY(
                        SPLIT(
                          FLATTEN(
                            FILTER(C3:C & "♦'♥" & SPLIT(D3:D, ",") & "|", C3:C <> "", D3:D <> "")
                          ),
                          "♥"
                        ),
                        "SELECT Col1, Col2, COUNT(Col2)
                         WHERE Col2 != '|'
                         GROUP BY Col1, Col2",
                      ),
                      "SELECT Col1, Col2
                       WHERE Col3 > 1",
                      1
                    ),
                    "SELECT MAX(Col2)
                     GROUP BY Col2
                     PIVOT Col1",
                  ),,
                  10^7
                )),
                "\|\s*$|(♦'|\|)\s*",
                "$1"
              ),
              "♦"
            ),
            2,
          )
        & "(?:,|$)"
      ), False),
        "err",
      True,
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Is it possible to know which part needs to be edited to ensure that only overlapping pages of duplicate courses return errors? It seems to also return errors for courses on day 5,6,7.

Comment: @Michael it does return err for every row if any of its page number could be seen multiple times for that course. Why there should be no error on days 5,6,7?

Comment: Oh wait, no. I'm dumb. Scratch my first comment. Again, thank you for the help.